# How do I create a grails 3 plugin which exposes a JSON view?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails3, json-view

In my custom Grails plugin, how can I set up a JSON view for a non-domain class and get client apps to use it by default?

I have a view file in the plugin:

```
/views/com/mycompany/myplugin/myclass/_myClass.gson
```

When I do `grails install`, I can see that this `.gson` file is in the generated JAR. However, the client app is not using it.

What can I do to  make it work?

Are there any settings or steps that can make troubleshooting easier?

I am using Grails 3.2.4.

**Update:**

When I copy the view into a client app, using the exact same path, the view is getting invoked. It's only when the view is defined in the plugin that the view cannot be found.

The framework seems to be trying to look up the plugin as a class from the classloader:
`myclientproject_com_mycompany_myplugin_myclass__myClass_gson`
How do I get my plugin to add this class to the classpath?

Comment: Probably an issue with the package name. See 2.15.3 http://views.grails.org/latest/#_plugin_support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case, what I actually needed was a custom converter.

See:

[In JSON views, how do I flatten an object out as a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053380/in-json-views-how-do-i-flatten-an-object-out-as-a-single-string/43053933#43053933)

This obviated the need for my plugin to publish a view.