# In JSON views, how do I flatten an object out as a single string?

Tags: json, grails, grails3, json-view

In my grails 3 app (I'm using grails 3.2.4), I have an object type which I want to be serialized as a string, for any Domain object that uses it:

```
class MyDomain1 {
    CustomId id
}

class MyDomain2 {
    CustomId id
}
```

I want to create a view that serializes CustomId as a string, rather than an object:

```
//instance of MyDomain1, in JSON format:
{
    "id": "123"
}
```

How can I do this without customizing the view for every object that uses CustomId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json views 1.2 supports a converter API that can do what you want

http://views.grails.org/latest/#_custom_converters

Comment: Thanks! For posterity, some notes on compatibility issues that James helped me with: To update the views plugin, set the version for "views-gradle" in *buildscript.dependencies* and "views-json*" in *dependencies*. This views plugin version also requires GORM version 6.1.0.RELEASE: add a property called gormVersion: "gormVersion=6.1.0.RELEASE" in gradle.properties.

Comment: It does not require GORM 6.1 under most conditions